# MySQL How can I add values of a column together and remove the duplicate rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day,

I have a MySQL table which has some duplicate rows that have to be removed while adding a value from one column in the duplicated rows to the original.

The problem was caused when another column had the wrong values and that is now fixed but it left the balances split among different rows which have to be added together. The newer rows that were added must then be removed.

In this example, the userid column determines if they are duplicates (or triplicates). userid 6 is duplicated and userid 3 is triplicated.

As an example for userid 3 it has to add up all balances from rows 3, 11 and 13 and has to put that total into row 3 and then remove rows 11 and 13. The balance columns of both of those have to be added together into the original, lower ID row and the newer, higher ID rows must be removed.

```
ID | balance | userid
---------------------
1  | 10      | 1
2  | 15      | 2
3  | 300     | 3
4  | 80      | 4
5  | 0       | 5
6  | 65      | 6
7  | 178     | 7
8  | 201     | 8
9  | 92      | 9
10 | 0       | 10
11 | 140     | 3
12 | 46      | 6
13 | 30      | 3
```

I hope that is clear enough and that I have provided enough info. Thanks =)

Comment: export it to excel. make it look right. then truncate the table and put it back the correct way from the now correct excel file. make sure there aren't any changes to the table while you are working on it

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I can't do this. The balances are being adjusted in the table constantly. I thought a purely MySQL method of doing it would be best because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps.

**1. Update:**

```
    UPDATE 
        tableX AS t
      JOIN
        ( SELECT userid
               , MIN(id) AS min_id
               , SUM(balance) AS sum_balance
          FROM tableX
          GROUP BY userid
        ) AS c
        ON  t.userid = c.userid
    SET
        t.balance = CASE WHEN t.id = c.min_id 
                        THEN c.sum_balance
                        ELSE 0 
                    END ;
```

**2. Remove the extra rows:**

```
    DELETE t
    FROM
        tableX AS t
      JOIN
        ( SELECT userid
               , MIN(id) AS min_id
          FROM tableX
          GROUP BY userid
        ) AS c
        ON  t.userid = c.userid
        AND t.id > c.min_id
    WHERE
        t.balance = 0 ;
```

---

Once you have this solved, it would be good to add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `userid` as it seems you want to be storing the balance for each user here. That will avoid any duplicates in the future. You could also remove the (useless?) `id` column.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(balance)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY userid
```

Should work, but the comment saying fix the table is really the best approach.

Comment: This is just showing me the balances of all the users. It doesn't solve the problem I am having. But thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table with the same structure and transfer the data to it with this query

```
insert into newPriceTable(id, userid, balance)
    select u.id, p.userid, sum(balance) as summation 
    from price p
    join (
        select userid, min(id) as id from price group by userid
    ) u ON p.userid = u.userid
    group by p.userid
```

Play around the query here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bb58/2

Comment: I can't use a new table the way it's setup. It potentially could work though otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Work is mainly done in MSSQL but you should be able to convert the syntax.

Using a GROUP BY UserID you can SUM() the Balance, join that back to your main table to update the balance across all the duplicates. Finally you can use RANK() to order your duplicate Userids and preserve only the earliest values.

I'd select all this into a new table and if it looks good, deprecate your old table and rename then new one.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/068ee/2

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know MSSQL so I'm not sure how to convert. Plus I can't really drop the table since its live.